# Gradient of a parametrization of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, tensor-products, matrix-calculus

I have seen several papers where it says more or less:

If $f : \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(X) = f(XX^\top)$ for matrices $\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ (under mild conditions) the gradient of the function $g(X) = f(XX^\top)$

$$\nabla g(X)  = (\nabla f(X X^\top)+\nabla f(XX^\top)) X.$$

I tried to get the previous expression using derivatives, and the definition of inner product for matrix spaces. So as first source I checked Magnus and Neudecker's fantastic book (as always) and I got a clue

$$D(XX^\top) = 2 N_n (X\otimes I_n),$$

in where $N_n$ is a symmetric idempotent matrix, $(I_{n^2}+ K_{nn})/2$ where $K_{nn} \text{vec} A = \text{vec}A^\top$.

*So I innocently thought, well let's apply the chaing rule and see where I can use the properties of $\text{vec}$ to put the inner product and find the gradient*. But If I blindly applied the chain rule, assuming that everything makes sense, it yields to

$$Dg(X) = 2 Df(XX^\top)N_n (X\otimes I_n).$$

So my question is, how can I connect the previous expression to get the gradient, i.e., how can I see that

$$Df(X)V = \langle \nabla g(X), V  \rangle = \text{Tr}(V^\top \nabla g(X)).$$

holds? I do not see it.

**I would really appreciate if you can help me out, or send me to an appropriate source to check this kind of problems**.

My intuition say that is not true. But If so, what the authors mean... (btw, I've seen this in several papers so maybe I am wrong)

---

I tried the differential  of $XX^\top$ by myself.

$$d(XX^\top)  = dXX^\top + X(dX)^\top$$

So vectorizing
$$d{\rm vec}(XX^\top) =  ((X \otimes I) + (I \otimes X) K) d{\rm vec}(X).$$

So $DXX^\top =  (X \otimes I) + (I \otimes X) K$ and by Chain rule leads to

$$Dg(X) = Df(XX^\top)((X \otimes I) + (I \otimes X) K)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=XX^T$ then the differential of $f$ is 
$$df = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right):dY$$
The function $g$ is the *same* function with a different parameterization, therefore
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right):d(XX^T) \\
 &= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right):(X\,dX^T+dX\,X^T) \\
 &= \left(\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right)^T+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right)\right)X:dX \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial X}
 &= \left(\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right)^T+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\right)\right)X \\
}$$
Based on this result, I think you've simply misread those papers.

**NB:** A colon is being used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer greg. I am trying to connect the dots with the definition presented by Magnus and Neudecker, and the definition through vec operator. I am wondering if you can add a little bit more. I truly appreciate it. By the way, is there any reference?

Comment: Towards the back of Magnus and Neudecker (around Ch 18)  they discuss the use of _differentials_.